# excel vba to put an excel range into body of gmail as plain text

Tags: excel, gmail, vba

I have found VBA code that will send email through Gmail that works but I cannot figure out how to get  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F59")` into the either `.TextBody` or `.HTMLBody`.

At first I thought it was because I had 2 ranges but now I am not so sure

My latest attempt was to copy in Excel but don't know how to paste as plain text that into Gmail (which I'm finding is different than Outlook)

```vb
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2()

Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant
 '    Dim rng As Range
Dim CELL As Range

 '    With Application
 '        .ScreenUpdating = False
 '        .EnableEvents = False
 '    End With

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "YOUREMAIL"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "YOURPASSWORD"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    .Update
End With


 '   Set rng =  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F59").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 '   Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 '   Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

 '    Set rng = Nothing
 '    On Error Resume Next

 '   Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 '   On Error GoTo 0

 '   If rng Is Nothing Then
 '       MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
 '              vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
 '       Exit Sub
 '   End If


 '    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
 '              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
 '              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
 '              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
 '              "This is line 4"


 '    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F59").Copy

For Each CELL In       Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If CELL.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
        If CELL.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(CELL.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then
            Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
 '        .To = "Mail address receiver"
    .To = CELL.Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    ' Note: The reply address is not working if you use this Gmail example
    ' It will use your Gmail address automatic. But you can add this line
    ' to change the reply address  .ReplyTo = "Reply@something.nl"
    .From = ""NAME""" <EMAIL>"
    .Subject = "CHANGESUBJECT"
    .TextBody = strboody
 '        .HTMLBody = (rng)
    .Send
End With
            Set iMsg = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next CELL

 '    With Application
 '        .EnableEvents = False
 '        .ScreenUpdating = False
 '    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this.

And I suggest you vist the page where this comes from at [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

```
Dim r as Range

    set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F59").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Then in part of the code that is doing the setup try this.

```
 .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(r)
```

This is the function.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hey - - - thanks - - - this is pretty advanced for me and not sure where it would go.

I did see this on Ron de Bruin's website but it also says it is for Outlook only - - - I need something that will work in gmail.

In his example in the file download that I tried the macro hangs at the  .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)  line

Comment: Solved - I found a link on Ron de Bruin's website that took me to another place that had some code to save a txt file and insert the file into the body